# Styled Components is bad practices for React Native?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Could you tell me please? Is it true that Styled Components is bad practices for React Native.

Better to use native *Stylesheet* of React Native.

**There is information that:**

React Native uses *StyleSheet* API to pass styles over the bridge most of the time. That API processes your styles and makes sure they’re passed only once over the bridge. During runtime, it substitutes the value of style prop with a numeric unique identifier that corresponds to the cached style on the native side.

As a result, rather than sending a large array of objects every time React Native is to rerender its UI, the bridge has to now deal with an array of numbers, which is much easier to process and transfer.

**And this information:**

You’re going to be sending a lot of static styles across the bridge to the native UI component on every render. React Native takes care of this with *Stylesheet* API by creating and supplying integers that reference a cached style definition. So when you use styles.myContainer you actually returning an integer referencing the style definition in Stylesheet.create().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response from the Styled Components developers.

Styled Components use StyleSheet.create under the hood in ReactNative.